# Weblogic 12c , MyFaces dependency injection

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I was reading some old blog about JSF and according to the author in case I am using a separate JSF implementation that is not part of the Weblogic I will not able to use dependency injection.

Currently I am using Weblogic 12c & MyFaces 2.1.8

Is this correct ?

Thanks

Comment: This blog http://buttso.blogspot.com/2011/03/jsf-with-managed-beans-and-dependency.html ? Have you tried it an encountered errors? I have not had any issues incorporating newer versions of JSF installed as a "shared library"

Comment: Thanks for the link I will give it a try, which version of my-faces are you using ?

Comment: Currently we have a mix (which is an interesting problem as well) of both jsf 1.2 and 2.1. You can add whatever version you need from the Deployments link in the admin console and target it to a specific server, which will override the weblogic default version.